# Character encoding confusing mysql

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have the following string which came from an excel document using codeplex php excel reader

```
Κύπρος / Kıbrıs
```

When i try and put this into mysql using php and mysqli the database string comes out as

```
ÎšÏÏ€ÏÎ¿Ï‚ / KÄ±brÄ±s
```

When i try and utf-decode it it comes out like this

```
?????? / K?br?s
```

However, when i try and put this string in manually into mysql it comes out fine.

Whats going on?

Comment: What is mysqli configured to use... `mysqli_character_set_name($link)`?

Comment: I ran this and i got latin1

Comment: Check out [mysqli_set_charset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php).

Answer (score 0):

When I connect to my MySQL Database I do it like this, to avoid problems:

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```